# Python GAE upload to Google Docs

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I need to upload a file/document to Google Docs on a GAE application. This should be simple enough, but I'm having a lot of trouble with the API.

The context:

```
import gdata.docs.service

client = gdata.docs.service.DocsService()
client.ClientLogin('gmail', 'pass')

ms = gdata.MediaSource(#what goes in here?)
client.Upload(media_source=ms, title='title')
```

To upload I'm using `client.Upload()`, which takes a MediaSource (wrapper) object as a parameter. However, `MediaSource()` seems to only accept a filepath for a document: `'C:/Docs/ex.doc'`.

Since I'm on GAE with no filesystem, I can only access the file through the Blobstore or a direct URL to the file. But how do I input that into `MediaSource()`?

There seems to be a [way in Java](http://blog.essaytagger.com/2011/07/how-to-upload-file-to-google-docs-when.html) to accomplish this by using `MediaByteArraySource()`, but nothing for Python.

Comment: [MediaIoBaseUpload](https://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/apiclient.http.MediaIoBaseUpload-class.html) of the [Google APIs Client Library for Python](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/) seems to be able to perform the upload from a stream.

Comment: Hm, how does this work with the gdata module? This seems completely separate.

Comment: I believe this is the Python module currently recommended to access the Google APIs as you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation).

Comment: I think you should use the Google Drive APIs now

Comment: @voscausa Is this to me or Pedro? I'm using the Document List API because the new Drive API doesn't support uploading a Google Document, only files (as far as I can tell).\

Comment: The Drive API is agnostic to the type of file. If (a) the source file has a recognised, compatible mime-type (say 'text/html' for example) and the upload is done with 'convert=true' then the result will be a Gdocs file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is curious, here's how I solved this problem using the Document List API.

I didn't want to use the [Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/) since it does complicate a lot of things. It's much simpler with the List API to just authenticate/login without the need for some OAuth trickery. This is using version 2.0.14 of the [gdata Python library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/downloads/list), which is not the current version (2.0.17), but it seems to have a simpler upload mechanism.

There's also slightly more (still sparse) documentation online for 2.0.14, though I had to piece this together from various sources and trial & error. The downside is that you cannot upload pdf's with this version. This code **will not** work with 2.0.17.

Here's the code:

```
import gdata.docs.service
import gdata.docs.data
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

# get file from url
result = urlfetch.fetch('http://example.com/test.docx')
headers = result.headers
data = result.content

# authenticate client object
client = gdata.docs.service.DocsService()
client.ClientLogin('gmail', 'password')

# create MediaSource file wrapper
ms = gdata.MediaSource(file_handle=result.content, 
content_type=headers['content-type'], 
content_length=int(headers['content-length']))

# upload specific folder, return URL of doc
google_doc_name = 'title'
folder_uri = '/feeds/folders/private/full/folder:j7XO8SJj...'
entry = client.Upload(ms, google_doc_name, folder_or_uri=secret.G_FOLDER_URI)
edit_url = entry.GetAlternateLink().href
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google Drive SDK docs include a complete sample application written in Python that runs on App Engine:

https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/python

You can use it as reference for your implementation and to see how to save a file from App Engine.

Comment: I commented above, but I was using the Document List API. I looked at the Drive SDK before but it doesn't seem to specify the difference between a Google Document and an arbitrary Drive file. Also, is there a way to upload to a predefined account like ClientLogin() in the Doc List API? It seems to only upload to the user's Google Account after authentication (there should be no authentication).

Comment: You can upload any kind of file to Drive and use the ?convert query parameter to control whether to keep it as file or convert it to the corresponding Google Docs format. There's no ClientLogin alternative as it is not a safe idea to require username and password

Comment: See my comment above re GDocs file on upload. On download, you can examine the mime-type to determine if the file is a Gdocs file. If you follow the OAuth flow, you end up with an access token which is bound to a user account. I'm not sure what you mean by "there should be no authentication" as clearly there must be. There are a number of different OAuth flows. There is probably one that will serve your needs.

Comment: Ah, I meant that the user should not have to authenticate anything; the authentication should be done completely on the backend, like with ClientLogin(). So any user of the GAE webapp should be able to upload a file which gets sent into **my** Drive. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. Check out Service Accounts https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount